# User-defined function with arbitrary parameter list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions

The Coalesce() built-in function accepts an arbitrary number of parameters.

Is it possible in SQL Server 2012 to write a user-defined function that does this, with the same syntax?  I don't want to use a table variable or comma-delimited list.

I want to implement a Coalesce() function that returns the LOWEST non-null element that's passed in rather than the FIRST non-null element that's passed in.  This is to meet a new user requirement.  Coalesce() doesn't require creating a table variable and, since I'm replacing the existing Coalesce() calls with new logic, I want to write my new function to behave the same way, including accepting an arbitrary number of elements.

I understand that there are other approaches that I could take here - I want to minimize the amount of re-writing that I have to do.

Comment: Kind of what it was intended for, specifically table variable parameter. I'd stay away from comma-delimited lists since you just have to turn it into a table afterwards. But a table valued parameter is the best option here. However, this could be an XY Problem, could you tell us what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can create a function with optional parameters and default values. (An example of an SP with optional parameters is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669437/creating-a-stored-procedure-with-an-indefinite-number-of-parameters/50731765#50731765).) That isn't the same as having an unpredictable number of `sql_variant` parameters, but it may be useful.

Comment: I have updated my initial question with additional details.

Comment: Can you define lowest

Comment: In my case, "earliest date".  But again, that's beside the point of the question, which is "can one write a UDF in SQL Server that accepts an arbitrary number of parameters, the way the Coalesce() function does?"

Comment: @Brian Here you get "accepted" answer. There is neither varargs nor overloading [T-SQL User defined function overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050700/t-sql-user-defined-function-overloading). Even CLR won't help you **meet your requirements** to create function that accepts parameters like `COALESCE`. EOT.

Comment: The question wasn't about overloading, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. just not in T-SQL.  You need to write a CLR function

Comment: Actually, @ALollz, this answers my question exactly.

Answer (score 0):

> *I don't want to use a table variable or comma-delimited list if I can avoid it.*

TVP is the way to go. But if you don't want to define table type you could use old-fashioned XML:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(id INT, a INT, b INT, c INT, d INT);
INSERT INTO tab(id,a,b,c,d) VALUES(1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO tab(id,a,b,c,d) VALUES(2,2,2,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO tab(id,a,b,c,d) VALUES(3,3,3,3,NULL);
INSERT INTO tab(id,a,b,c,d) VALUES(4,4,4,4,4);
```

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.my_func(@input XML)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN
(
  SELECT SUM(a.b.value('.', 'INT'))   --any logic here, for simplicity's sake SUM
  FROM @input.nodes('/*') AS sub(c)
  CROSS APPLY sub.c.nodes('@*') a(b)
);
END;
```

And call:

```
SELECT t1.*, sub.*, dbo.my_func(sub.x) AS result
FROM tab t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT a,b,c,d
             FROM (SELECT 1) t2(q) FOR XML AUTO) sub(x);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=15264a75cb3d33a082c76f7cc2ca3a15)**

Output:

```
┌────┬───┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───────────────────────────────┬────────┐
│ id │ a │  b   │  c   │  d   │               x               │ result │
├────┼───┼──────┼──────┼──────┼───────────────────────────────┼────────┤
│  1 │ 1 │ null │ null │ null │ <t2 a="1"/>                   │      1 │
│  2 │ 2 │ 2    │ null │ null │ <t2 a="2" b="2"/>             │      4 │
│  3 │ 3 │ 3    │ 3    │ null │ <t2 a="3" b="3" c="3"/>       │      9 │
│  4 │ 4 │ 4    │ 4    │ 4    │ <t2 a="4" b="4" c="4" d="4"/> │     16 │
└────┴───┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───────────────────────────────┴────────┘
```

## EDIT:

No, it is not possible to define UDF with variable args like `COLAESCE`. The best you can get is:

```
LOWEST2(a1, a2)
LOWEST3(a1, a2, a3)
LOWEST4(a1, a2, a3, a4)
...
LOWESTn(a1, a2, a3, a4, ..., an)
```

Please note that function names are different. Plus you need to use data type that will satisfy most of your cases or even `sqlvariant`.

Comment: This is not a user-defined function that accepts an arbitrary number of parameters the way Coalesce() does.

Comment: @Brian No in pure T-SQL you can't do what you want. I answered your second part. Correct way is TVP.

Comment: No, you didn't, because passing in an XML string is not the "same syntax" as the Coalesce() function.

Comment: While your comments are true @Brian this is a native way without changing server defaults and introducing something as vast as CLR which wouldn't be as easy to implement, as portable, etc.

Comment: Perhaps, @scsimon, but that doesn't change the fact that Lukasz's reply **did not meet my needs**.  I asked "Is it possible to do X?  Here is why I want to do X", and this reply is a long-winded "Here's how to do Y, which is similar and is what I think you should do instead."

Comment: @Brian I am pretty sure that even using CLR you won't get function signature with varargs `LOWEST(a1,a2, ..., an)`. The best what you will get is `LOWEST2(a1, a2)`, `LOWEST3(a1, a2, a3)`, `LOWEST4(a1, a2, a3, a4)` and so on. This is not the same as `COALESCE`. Please post your version when you have it(but I highly doubt it is achievable).

Comment: Second `Perhaps, @scsimon, but that doesn't change the fact that Lukasz's reply did not meet my needs.` by `"TVP is the way to go."` I **implicitly** stated that it is not possible in a way you proposed.